# array semantics for computed value

Tags: knockout.js

I have a `ko.computed()` function that proxies a collection like this:

```
function ListView(query) {
    var self = this;

    this.query = query;
    this.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    ko.computed( function() {
        self.items( self.query() == null ? [] : self.query().postings() );
    }

    // more code
}
```

Unfortunately, this causes the `self.items()` variable to change with every change to every object in the postings() array. What I would rather do is have a computed value items represent the query's postings directly. But if I do this:

```
 self.items = ko.computed(function() { return self.query().postings(); });
```

the value becomes a scalar, not an array, as far as Knockout is concerned. The reasons this matters is that as some of the items in the list change state, I would like to update just those parts of the display, rather than re-rendering the entire list. This is not just a performance optimization (although with hundreds of items performance is also an issue), but also I am trying to log which items are currently being displayed to keep track of what the user might have seen.

I suppose logically, I would like to have something like this:

```
  self.items = self.query().postings;
```

but this breaks if the query changes because (I think) the dependencies exist on a different object.

Is there a clean way to build a dependency mechanism and still preserve collection semantics?

*EDITED: 13 May 2012*

I tried to implement the extension approach suggested by @MichaelBest, but that produced the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function dependentObservable() {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            set.apply(dependentObservable, arguments);
        } else {
            return get();
        }
    } has no method 'valueWillMutate'
ko.utils.arrayForEach.ko.observableArray.fn.(anonymous function)    knockout-2.1.0.debug.js:1087
SubviewModel.self.refresh.self.doSort    SummaryViewModel.js:73
ko.ignoreDependencies    knockout-deferred-updates.js:172
subFnObj.(anonymous function).newCallback    knockout-deferred-updates.js:188
ko.subscribable.fn.notifySubscribers    knockout-2.1.0.debug.js:870
ko.utils.arrayForEach    knockout-2.1.0.debug.js:85
ko.subscribable.fn.notifySubscribers    knockout-2.1.0.debug.js:866
evaluateImmediate    knockout-deferred-updates.js:300
evaluatePossiblyAsync    knockout-deferred-updates.js:246
ko.subscribable.fn.notifySubscribers    knockout-2.1.0.debug.js:870
ko.utils.arrayForEach    knockout-2.1.0.debug.js:85
ko.subscribable.fn.notifySubscribers    knockout-2.1.0.debug.js:866
ko.observable.observable.valueHasMutated    knockout-2.1.0.debug.js:946
observable    knockout-2.1.0.debug.js:934
updateViewModel    knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js:514
changes    knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js:389
visitPropertiesOrArrayEntries    knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js:569
updateViewModel    knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js:374
ko.mapping.fromJS    knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js:91
Topic.load    querium.js:1212
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a computed observable that returns an array and acts like an `observableArray`:

```
self.items = ko.computed({
    read: function() { return self.query().postings(); }
    write: function(value) { self.query().postings(value); }
});
ko.utils.extend(self.items, ko.observableArray.fn);
```

Now you can use all the functions that an `observableArray` has with `items`.

Edit: This approach will only work if you also add `valueWillMutate` and `valueHasMutated` functions to the object:

```
self.items.valueWillMutate = function () { self.query().postings.valueWillMutate(); }
self.items.valueHasMutated = function () { self.query().postings.valueHasMutated(); }
```

And this will also only work if you use the *debug* version of Knockout, because in the *minified* version, the function names will be compressed.

Comment: I had a problem with propagating updates with this approach. See the post for the stack trace.

Comment: The fact that self.query() could return null gave me some trouble, but I think I got this to work eventually.

Comment: Would it make sense to add this logic to the library? Ideally, you could say `this.dep = ko.computed(fcn, this, {semantics: 'array'});`. Barring that, `this.foo = ko.observable(); this.dep = ko.computed(fcn, this); ko.utils.extend(this.dep, ko.observableArray.fn, this.foo);`

Comment: I'm not sure how much demand there is for this. Also your extend example won't work properly because the functions copied from ko.observable will be wrong.

Comment: I'd like to add that the method I've provided is unsupported and may break in later versions of Knockout (>2.1).

Comment: Thanks for the caveat! I do encourage the authors of Knockout to consider integrating this feature into a future version, as it makes it easier to represent certain kinds of data structures using the natural KnockoutJS idiom.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `computed` return an observable:

`self.items = ko.computed(function() { return self.query().postings; });`

Then you can use the proxied `observableArray` like this:

`self.items().push(...);`

To access the underlying array, you'd have to unwrap both observables:

`var postingsArray = self.items()();`

Comment: I am going to give this a try... but it sure does make the code more complicated to understand. Would be nice to be able to specify the semantics of a computed value declaratively.